# Get the price of tokens with web3js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, web3py

I wanted to know if it was possible to get the price of tokens with web3.js
For example I would like to get the price of WBTC on Uniswap and on SushiSwap

If you have any documentation or tutorials I'm interested

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need any price information you could use chainlink oracle. Here is official docs for evm data feeds;
https://docs.chain.link/docs/using-chainlink-reference-contracts/ .

For a simple implementation example you can take a look at freeCodeCamp.org 's 32-hour course/lesson4 on youtube.

Also you can take a look at uniswap API ;  https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/API/entities

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be compatible across multiple chains and multiple DEXs, the easiest way I could think of is to call the router by using the method getAmountsOut.

```
router.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [inAddress, outAddress]).call()
```

amountIn would be 1 * Math.pow(10, inAddress token decimals)
inAddress is WBTC address
outAddress is USDC address

The output will be:

```
100000000,22397189858
```

Output[0] is amount in. Output[1] is amount out. You then have to divide that by
(1 * Math.pow(10, out address decimal), where you will get WBTCprice: 22397.189858

The only caveat of doing this method is that you need to know the stable pair that exist on that dex. Some dex may use WBTC/USDT, some may use WBTC/USDC.